# How to implement full text search in NoSQL database?

Tags: mongodb, elasticsearch, solr, full-text-search, nosql

Has anyone tried to deploy NoSQL database with Full Text Search feature?
I read a lot of topics here in StackOverFlow and some other sites but they were all in 2011 and 2012 which I think there are a lot of updates to this moment.

I have a project that requires a full text search feature and I am trying to pick the right NoSQL database.
I am thinking also of ElasticSearch and Solr to enable this feature?

Is MongoDB Full Text Search Feature working fine? or it has performance and scalability issues?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

The MongoDb full text search feature works well from version 2.6, however, its full text search feature relies on a `text` index and you can only add one such index per collection. Depending on your exact requirements, this may be too limiting. Check the MongoDB [documentation](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/index-text/) for more details. If you need a more flexible full text search functionality, Elasticsearch will be a better option.

Comment: Thank you jaco for your answer,
Do you recommend any certain documents or references to help me in this? As I am still building my knowledge in MongoDB and Elasticsearch as well

Answer (score 0):

Elasticsearch is working pretty good. You can use analyzers to stem your text. Also you can store your data in JSON format. It has "match_phrase" function allowing you to make full text search in a field that you want to search. Take a look at that.You can find documentations here : https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-search.html